# How to handle a psychic damage roll

Tags: dnd-5e, hit-points, damage-resistance, damage-types, solo

I’m playing a D&D solo adventure called "[To Hell and Back Again](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/288363/To-Hell-and-Back-Again)", I've just had to roll a d10 for psychic damage, due to a 'trait' called 'fear of bony things'. I entered a vehicle which had skeletons inside, I don't know, they must have hygiene problems, not to clear them out.

My question is: is this just a straight-forward roll which comes off of my current hit points? Is there any way to reduce the damage?

Quote from the adventure:

> B16 - **Inside the Infernal War Machine**
> Machine and close the door behind you, its hinges creaking with rust.
> The interior of this large vehicle seems to be able to seat up to eight individuals, and several of the seats in the back are currently occupied by several sandblasted skeletons. You feel a cold chill run down your spine as the wind howls hungrily outside of the machine. The skeletons rattle a bit, and one of their hands falls off, disappearing beneath a back seat. If you have marked on your character sheet the *Fear of Bony Things* trait, take 1d10 psychic damage.

Comment: there are plenty of ways to reduce damage, but we don't know which, if any, your character has.

Comment: @DaveDiamond We need more details to answer your question. Providing a quote from the adventure might help us understand what is going on.

Comment: Based on the description, this appears to be [this D&D 5e solo adventure](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/288363/To-Hell-and-Back-Again). I've added the [tag:dnd-5e] and [tag:solo] tags.

Answer (score 10):

When you "take 1d10 damage", roll 1d10 and reduce your hit point total by that amount.

There's no way to reduce the damage taken, unless you happen to have some magic item or ability on your character sheet which reduces psychic damage or damage in general. This mainly appears in a trait like damage resistance; e.g. resistance to psychic type damage. It's rare to have this at the 1st to 3rd level, where this adventure module takes place.

Comment: An example of a class feature that gives such resistance is the Sorcerer subclass Aberrant Mind: at 6th level "Psychic Defenses: *You gain resistance to psychic damage, and you have advantage on saving throws against being charmed or frightened.*"

Answer (score 4):

### This is just a straight damage roll

In 5e, damage has types like bludgeoning for a mace, slashing for an axe, fire for a fire bolt spell. Or in this case, psychic.

These damage types interact with other game features, such as vulnerability, resistance and immunity that certain creatures have to double, half or ignore the damage (see page 195 PHB, **Damage and Healing**).

> Different attacks, damaging spells, and other harmful effects deal different types of damage. Damage types have no rules of their own, but other rules, such as damage resistance, rely on the types.

Very few creatures are resistant to psychic damage, and as a normal wizard of level 1 you should not have any such resistance, unless you found and are using a magic item that says so. So you just roll the damage and deduct the result from your hp.

Comment: Thanks very much, it's a big hit, but there you go. Do you think I should leave the rests to the module, or should I spend hit dice to heal, if these things are mutually exclusive?

Comment: I don’t know the module, but if I survived this as a level one wizard (a high roll could be deadly easily), unless I rolled very low like a 1, 2, or 3, I would very likely take a HD if I can. Probably depends how close to 0 you are - if you only have 1 hp left *anything* could down you

Comment: Whether you can take short or long rests depends on whether you can finish the rest without it being interrupted (e.g. by monster attacks). If a short rest is interrupted, you need to start it over to get any benefit from it; if a long rest is interrupted, you can resume the rest as long as it's not an interruption of 1 hour or more. [See the rules on resting here.](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#Resting)

Answer (score 1):

### It works just like any regular damage roll

Just roll the dice that it tells you to, 1d10 in this case and deduct the result from your HP, unless you happen to have any temporary hit points, then you reduce those first and only apply the leftover damage to your HP.

In order to reduce the damage, you would generally have to have a resistance to damage type that the damage is of, they’re not very common but not unheard of either, it’s sometimes included in racial traits (e.g. Shadar-kai gets resistance to necrotic as a racial feature, Aasimar gets necrotic and radiant, Tiefling gets fire resistance, Goliath gets cold resistance, etc.), there are also class features that give resistances, it can also come from a magic item. Psychic damage is one of the least resisted damage types though, I can’t think of any PC trait that gives it.

Comment: One of the Ravnica races has it I think

Comment: @SeriousBri Kalashtar from Eberron but that's an entire different setting, most of Eberron races aren't balanced for a non-Eberron game